# Unable to execute Java in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: java, mysql, database, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to connect to MYSQL database and my program **Sync_DB_RegCheck.java** is working perfect in Eclipe. But I wanted to execute and run the same program in **Ubuntu 12.04 Terminal** .But I am getting errors following during Execution.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Sync_DB_RegCheck
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Sync_DB_RegCheck
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: SYNC_APP.bin.Sync_DB_RegCheck. Program will exit.
```

My Java program **Sync_DB_RegCheck.java**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;


public class Sync_DB_RegCheck {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {


         Connection conn = null;
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=root");
        System.out.println("Connected?");
        try{
              Statement st = (com.mysql.jdbc.Statement) conn.createStatement();
              st.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE del");
              System.out.println ("Table Deletion process is completly successfully!");
              }

        catch(SQLException s){
              System.out.println("Table is not exists!");
              }

}}
```

Compilation code : this is compiling the program without error

```
$java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar Sync_DB_RegCheck.java
```

Execution code : which gave the above mentioned errors

```
java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar Sync_DB_RegCheck
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `java` command contains a `-cp` option, which specifies the classpath: the location where the JVM will look for classes to use.

This classpath contains the MySQL driver, which is good. But it does not contain the current directory (indicated by `.`), where your `Sync_DB_RegCheck.class` file resides. So you need to add that one too:

```
java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar Sync_DB_RegCheck
```